# Looking at this sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^n}g(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am just observing this sum type $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^n}g(n)\tag1$$

I tried varies functions of $g(n)$ then I came upon this one

$g(n)=\frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)^4-(2k)^4}$ which does give a neat closed form, but I can't prove it.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\cdot\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^n}\cdot\frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)^4-(2k)^4}=-\frac{\pi\tanh(k\pi)}{64k^3}\tag2$$

where $k\ge 1$

**How do we prove $(2)?$**

Comment: What was the motivation to try various functions $g(n)$?

Comment: See what $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}$ simplifies to. You might start by computing several terms.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966942/evaluating-sum-frac11n2n4) is closely related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
&=\frac{2^nn!}{\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^nn!}}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}=\frac1{2n+1}
$$
Therefore, using Partial Fractions and $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179),
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^4-x^4}
&=\frac1{2x^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{(2n+1)^2-x^2}-\frac1{(2n+1)^2+x^2}\right]\\
&=\frac1{4x^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{(2n+1)-x}-\frac1{(2n+1)+x}\right]\\
&-\frac1{4ix^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{(2n+1)-ix}-\frac1{(2n+1)+ix}\right]\\
&=-\frac1{8x^3}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n+\frac{1+x}2}+\frac1{8ix^3}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n+\frac{1+ix}2}\\
&=-\frac\pi{8x^3}\cot\left(\pi\frac{1+x}2\right)+\frac\pi{8ix^3}\cot\left(\pi\frac{1+ix}2\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi{8x^3}\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)-\frac\pi{8x^3}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)
\end{align}
$$
Plug in $x=2k$.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/967894) gives a disguised version of this approach (using $\pi\cot(\pi z)$ and contour integration instead of $\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{k+z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your summand simplifies to $\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4-(2k)^4}$, and from there you have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4-(2k)^4}=\frac{\pi[\tan(\pi k)-\tanh(\pi k)]}{64k^3}$. You get your result from assuming $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This from @robjohn 's comment: $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Mathematica: `Assuming[n>=0 && Element[n,Integers], (2n)!!/(2n+1)!! Binomial[2n,n]/4^n // FullSimplify]`

Comment: Could you supply a proof of the equality $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4-(2k)^4}=\frac{\pi[\tan(\pi k)-\tanh(\pi k)]}{64k^3}$?

Comment: Mathematica again: `Sum[1/((2 n + 1)^4 - (2 k)^4), {n, 0, Infinity}]` assuming that they've done it right ;-)

Comment: I would prefer an old-fashion step-by-step derivation.