# Find $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{n^{2}}{n^{8}+n^{4}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{n^{2}}{n^{8}+n^{4}+1}$

This series is equivalent to  $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{n^{4} - n^{2} +1} - \frac{1}{n^{4} + n^{2} +1}$

Them I'm stuck. Any hint$?$

Comment: @joriki There should be, on partial fractions...?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/966942.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You properly wrote $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{2}}{n^{8}+n^{4}+1}=\frac 12\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{4} - n^{2} +1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{4} + n^{2} +1} \right)$$

Now,  write
$$\frac{1}{n^{4} - n^{2} +1}=\frac{1}{(n^2-a)(n^2-b)}=\frac 1 {a-b}\left(\frac 1 {n^2-a}-\frac 1 {n^2-b}\right)$$ 
$$\frac{1}{n^{4} + n^{2} +1}=\frac{1}{(n^2-c)(n^2-d)}=\frac 1 {c-d}\left(\frac 1 {n^2-c}-\frac 1 {n^2-d}\right)$$ 
which means that you face a series of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2-k}=\frac{1-(\pi  \sqrt{k}) \cot \left(\pi  \sqrt{k}\right)}{2 k}$$

For the first summation, you have $a=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$. For the second summation $c=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $d=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$. That is to say
$$\sqrt a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \qquad \sqrt b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\qquad \sqrt c=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}\qquad \sqrt d=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

All of the above makes
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{4} - n^{2} +1}=\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{\pi  \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right)+3 \sinh
   (\pi )\right)}{\cosh (\pi )-\cos \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right)}-3\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{4} + n^{2} +1}=\frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{3} \pi  \tanh \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right)-3\right)$$
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{2}}{n^{8}+n^{4}+1}=\frac{\pi \sqrt 3}{12} \left(\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right)+\sqrt{3} \sinh (\pi )+\tanh \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}
   \pi }{2}\right) \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right)-\cosh (\pi )\right) } { \cosh (\pi )-\cos \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right)}\right)}$$

Comment: Could you point me to a derivation of this series for the hyperbolic cotangent?